# Why is my database table being corrupted?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am overseeing a database for a client that has had their `wp_posts` table get corrupted twice in the past week. When I try to access the table using PhpMyAdmin, I get the following message:

> The table `wp_posts` has been marked as crashed and must be repaired.

There is no indication as to how this happened or what can be done to prevent it. I've been a developer for 8 years and have never experienced this before, so I'm at a loss. Has anybody experience this issue and how can I deal with it before it happens again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message has no idea how it happened. It could be a faulty disk, an incomplete I/O write, a bug in MySQL code, or someone could have opened the file and scribbled in it with an editor.

What can be done to fix it is to use the `myisamchk` table repair tool that is included with MySQL. How to use this tool is covered here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-repair.html

What can be done to prevent it? **Stop using the MyISAM storage engine.**

MyISAM was once considered to be more stable and more high-performance, but that was over 10 years ago. InnoDB has received all the engineering improvements since then, it is significantly higher in performance than MyISAM, and it's much safer in terms of self-repair. Gradually in each release of MySQL, MyISAM is being deprecated.

Changing the storage engine is as simple as:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You have to do this for each table in your database, one at a time. But you can generate the set of commands to run:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ENGINE=InnoDB;') AS _sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

Capture the output of that query and run the statements as an SQL script. In 99% of cases, there's no benefit to using MyISAM if you're using a current version of MySQL (e.g. any GA release in the 5.5 branch or later).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Bill! When I try to run the mysiamchk tool, it says that it can't create a new tempfile. I then noticed that the `wp_posts` says it is in use (and it has been like that all day). I found this article (https://portal.my-tss.com/knowledgebase/254/MySQL-Table-says-IN-USE-but-table-will-not-repair-in-phpmyadmin.html) which describes how to work around that, but when I try to SSH into the folder for my DB, it says Permission denied. My hosting provider tech support has no idea why I wouldn't have permission to `cd` into that folder. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not unusual for the MySQL data directory to have limited permissions. By default, the directory is accessible to the user 'mysql,' or root of course.

Comment: So if the `wp_posts` table is stuck `in use`, then there is no way to repair that table?

Comment: Try the `--safe-recover` option. Read in the page I linked to: "If the preceding step fails, use myisamchk --safe-recover tbl_name. Safe recovery mode uses an old recovery method that handles a few cases that regular recovery mode does not (but is slower)."

Comment: But if I am not able to `cd` into the MYSQL data directory, then I can't run that command with the `--safe-recover` option, right? Or should I run that from within the the mysql database as a query?

Comment: It's a shell command, not a query. You do need access to the data directory. If you don't have access, get your hosting provider to help you.